# SDK Mismatch Errors UNSUPPORTED_SDK_VERSION_ERROR on android from OSX development

Tags: microsoft-band

using android studio 1.5.1

JRE 1.6.0

with the newest Android band sdk microsoft-band-1.3.20105.2.jar

developing on osx 10.11.2

targeting a galaxy not SDK version 22 (min version stated as 17)

trying to run the sample code

```
BandInfo[] devices = BandClientManager.getInstance().getPairedBands();
```

throws

```
UNSUPPORTED_SDK_VERSION_ERROR
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the error message is "The version of Microsoft Health installed does not support this application. Please update to the latest version of Microsoft Health.".

So, all you should have to do is update the version of Microsoft Health you have installed on your phone.

Each new version of the Microsoft Band SDK appears to only work with the latest version of Microsoft Health, as it is that application that holds on to the Band's Bluetooth connection.

Comment: thanks, I figured it would be obvious.  I thought it was referring to the android SDK since there was warnings about no SDK below 19 during import.